# KVM vs container vs virtual box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kvm

What is the main difference between KVM, container and virtualbox, if several VMs to be run on one server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Containers are not VMs for very very strong simplification application/service virtualisation.

KVM and Virtualbox are VMs managers/hypervisors, but they cannot be run simultanously (because of busy ressources about VTx busy).

Of course you can run  many VMs on same host if performances ares ok.

You may read [this](http://davidokwii.com/linux-virtualization-and-containers-virtualbox-kvm-xen-lxc-and-docker/). It is a roughy description of the basic formulas and softwares in the virtualization in Linux environment today.

Comment: so which one do you think more relevan if I wan to run a windows program on my private centos linux server?

Comment: you need windows OS so visualization will be the good choice.  if it is your firsts VM experiments Virtualbox is the good choice.

Comment: I'm already using VirtualBox for window applications, However I wanted to get more detail in KVM or Docker for some industrial windows based program. Thank you

Comment: Don't post links without at least a short decription, what is there. It is because the link rotting problem (if the remote site goes away, your answer becomes unusable), and because your answers should be comprehensible without clicking.

Comment: @Shahram First, if you have a new question, then ask a new question, it is welcomed. What is not welcomed, asking another question in a comment below the answer you've got. Be also more specific for your question, if you only want to know more about these technologies, then simply search for other questions about them (here or on the google), and then ask here what is unclear.

Comment: I am not sure, that KVM and virtualbox couldn't be run on the same machine, maybe in the IOMMU or CPU virtualization flags there may be some conflicts, but probably their usage can be switched off at least in one of the sides. But I surely wouldn't do this in a productive environment.

Comment: @peterh thank yo very much for your comments and consideration answering my question. I have read many resources and wikis on internet but couldn't find any clear answer specially for industrial applications and made me more confused. That's why I cannot came with such a question. I will delete it if that causeing any issue

Comment: @Shahram If you ask something which is not a general description of them (what you can find anywhere on the net), and the answer can't be found with a simple google query, then also this is welcomed. The main problem what I see, that I can't see the specific, answerable question what you ask. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @Shahram If you only want to learn them, then simply install them. What is not clear, ask on google. If you hit a problem what you can't solve on this way (very likely), yes, then it will be already an answerable question.